# Iterate through MongoDB collection with Meteor.js

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I m learning Meteor and I m building a very basic app for practice purposes.
I just installed Collection FS and I m uploading files using the cfs:filesystem.
I have a collection named todos witch has the following fields among others :

```
"files" : [ "/cfs/files/files/HPxaJrEbvNjcnmA6m/files?store=files", "/cfs/files/files/jfKua2BszyfqiKYYu/files?store=files" ]
```

The insert is done via method on Server side:

```
'addFiles':function(id,url){
  todos.update(id, {
    $push: {files:url}
  });
```

How can I iterate through these to put them in urls in my template?

What I tried in my template is :

```
{{#each todos}}
{{#each files}}<a href="{{files}}" target="_blank"> file</a>{{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Buts this renders just `<a target="_blank"> file</a>`
In case the files object hasn't got any values I dont want to show any url.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are properly subscribing to `todos` collection and have helper:

```
Template.NAME.helpers({
    todos : function(){
       return todos.find();
    }
})
```

In template NAME try this:

```
{{#each todos}}
   {{#each this.files}}
     <a href="{{this}}" target="_blank"> file</a>
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

If `files` is empty, then nothing will be shown.

Comment: Brilliant! I m accepting your answer as soon as SO lets me. Thank you very much! I didnt know about {{this}} attribute.